# Shell Script Nested If assignment

Tags: shell, unix

Wha is wrong with the following code

```
         $var11="Inactive"
         if [[ $k = 'Activated' ]];then
               if [[ $v == 'Yes' ]];then
                      var11="Active"
               fi
         fi
```

It goes inside the first if but not inside the second. When I echo, it also prints $v value as 'Yes'

Comment: If you really pasted here your original script, it should issue an error message, such as _=Inactive - command not found_. Aside from this, you can do a `set -x` to see what's going wrong.

Comment: With a script of such a simple structure, you could provide a __reproducible example__ and specify, what result you expect, and what result you get instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since this snippet of code prints `yes`:

```
k=Activated; v=Yes
if [[ $k = 'Activated' ]] ; then
    if [[ $v == 'Yes' ]] ; then
        echo yes
    fi
fi
```

I suggest you check your value of `$v` again. You can do that with something like from the following transcript:

```
pax> echo -n "$v" | od -xcb
0000000    6559    0073
          Y   e   s
        131 145 163
0000003
```

You should have those three (and *only* those three) characters. Anything else will not be considered equal (including things that contain non-printing characters that may not be obvious in a simple `echo` of the variable).

---

As an aside, you do *not* want to do this:

```
$var11="Inactive"
```

The general rule is that you use the "naked" variable name to set a value, and the `$` prefix to use it, unless you're using the more advanced `Bash` facilities like `((...))`:

```
pax> var11=42
pax> echo ${var11}
42
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a space issue, I was revisiting the syntax again and again. But yes it was one of those off days.